# Does MariaDB support ST_Distance_Sphere?

Tags: mariadb, spatial

Running `mariadb`, I'm getting

> ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION `ST_Distance_Sphere` does not exist

When I run a basic query like

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere( POINT(0,0), POINT(0,1) );
```

However, I'm using a pretty new version.

```
Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB-1 Ubuntu 17.10
```

What's going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 10.2+

This issue has been fixed and backported with [MDEV-13467](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467). It's available 10.2.38, 10.3.29, 10.4.19, 10.5.10

Find [their support matrix here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlmariadb-spatial-support-matrix/).

Answer (score 2):

`ST_Distance_Sphere` was added only recently to MySQL -- 5.7.6.  10.1 is not the newest; there is 10.2 and 10.3.  Sure, 10.1.25 came out recently (2017-07-04), but the development effort has shifted to 10.2.x and 10.3.x .

Feel free to file a feature request with MariaDB.

Comment: Feature request is already filled [MDEV-13467](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13467)